# What kind of controller does Spring internally implement when @controller is used

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Since there are many types of controllers in Spring2.5 version, what kind of controller does Spring internally implement when @controller is used? and how does spring decide what controller to implement?

Comment: Can you use Spring 3.X? It has better @Controller hanling, controllers are ordinary, only annotated, beans.

Comment: Yeah I am using Spring3 now, however my question is how does @controller actually work, how does spring know what type of controller to implement. For example in spring2.5 we have controllers like abstractcontroller, simpleformcontroller etc...so using annotated controllers will internally implement which flavour of controller??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer:** It doesn't matter how @Controller is implemented internally.

**Long answer:**

First you should [read the reference manual](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-controller) to know the API, which is primarly based on annotations. You have no `AbstractController`, `SimpleFormController` etc. Important sentence:

> The `@Controller` annotation indicates that a particular class serves
>   the role of a controller. **Spring does not require you to extend any
>   controller base class** or reference the Servlet API.

You must abandon "Spring MVC 2.5 thinking" and just define beans annotated with `@Controller` like

```
@Controller
public class ClinicController {

    private final Clinic clinic;

    @Autowired
    public ClinicController(Clinic clinic) {
        this.clinic = clinic;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public void welcomeHandler() {
    }

    @RequestMapping("/vets")
    public ModelMap vetsHandler() {
        return new ModelMap(this.clinic.getVets());
    }

}
```

and just use them as ordinary beans (by adding to servlet.xml `<bean class="com.example.ClinicController " />`). It's much easier this way.